# What to do when link requires cookies to function in app

Tags: ios, http, cookies, swift3

So when I send request without any cookies I get an error.
when trying to get request manually (in a browser) I first need to go to homepage, which loads 4 cookies, then the request can proceed without error. Some experimenting showed that I need only one of the cookies.

This is completely new to me and any snippets/guides on how this can be implemented are welcome. I understand that this question Is pretty vague but I am lost in where to start looking and would appreciate any help

```
let url = URL(string: "homepage")
        var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil, let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                print("response1")
                print("error = \(error)")
                print("response = \(response)")
                return
            }
            if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) {
                print("responseObject = \(json)")
            } else {
                print("response2")
                print("responseString = \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))")
            }

            let url2 = URL(string: "requestpage")
            var request = URLRequest(url: url2!)
            request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
                guard let data = data, error == nil, let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
                    print("response2")
                    print("error = \(error)")
                    print("response = \(response)")
                    return
                }
                if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) {
                    print("responseObject = \(json)")
                } else {
                    print("response2")
                    print("responseString = \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))")
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
        task.resume()
```

Comment: Your code handling the first response has a `print("response2")`; Surely that should say `response1`, not `response2`?

Comment: Are your web pages return JSON or HTML?

Comment: yah silly me, but it still does not seem to work, they return html, my code became intertwined jumble at this point, so i tried into your example, it should have worked though. not sure what happened

Comment: Well, that's fine. If they return HTML, they return HTML. (But if that's the case, it makes no sense to try to parse JSON if they return HTML.) The point is that when you get the response (whether JSON or HTML is immaterial) from the 1st request, and if that response included a cookie, then when you issue the 2nd request, the cookie returned by the 1st response will be provided in the 2nd request. It all happens automatically. You don't have to write any "cookie" code. You just have to make sure you make request of the home page (which returns cookie) before issuing subsequent requests.

Comment: yes, i get the point but while the first request printed out homepage, second still gives error. Ill double check things in the morning, getting really late, thanks for help, ill update on how it goe

Comment: By the way, consider using a tool like [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com) or [WireShark](http://wireshark.org) and you'll see everything going back and forth. And look at both cookies and hidden fields.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you should:

- initiate `URLSessionTask` for the landing page that sets the cookies;
- that will, with no intervention on your part, will set the cookies in your `URLSession`;
- after that response is successfully received, you can then send the next request and the cookies should be there automatically with no extra code.

Unless you did something to explicitly interfere with this process, `URLSession` seamlessly receives the the cookies and includes them in subsequent requests for you.

If you're scraping a web site (and if so, please check the ToS to make sure it's permitted), you are well advised to request the pages in the same order that a web browser would. It might feel like you could bypass that landing page and set the cookies yourself, but often the cookie values are generated dynamically and you can have problems if you try to bypass that landing page.

---

You asked for an example, and there's really not much to show. Just initiate second request from the completion of the first request. There's not a single reference to cookies in the Swift code. `URLSession` takes care of everything:

```
let url = baseURL.appendingPathComponent("setcookie.php")
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard error == nil, let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
        print("error = \(error)")
        print("response = \(response)")
        return
    }

    let url = baseURL.appendingPathComponent("results.php")
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil, let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode == 200 else {
            print("error = \(error)")
            print("response = \(response)")
            return
        }
        if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) {
            print("responseObject = \(json)")
        } else {
            print("responseString = \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
task.resume()
```

My first page, `setcookie`, just set a cookie:

```
<?php

setcookie("foo", "bar", time()+3600);

$result = array("success" => true);
echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

And my second page retrieved the cookies:

```
<?php

$result = array("success" => true);
if (isset($_COOKIE))
    $result["_COOKIE"] = $_COOKIE;

header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

And the above Swift code output:

```
responseObject = {
    "_COOKIE" =     {
        foo = bar;
    };
    success = 1;
}
```

Comment: sorry to ask, but could you please include a simple example ?

Comment: and yes, I have permission

Comment: I've added an example, but there's literally nothing you have to do to support cookies in `URLSession`. Just make the first request, make sure it succeeded, and then issue second request. If it's not working for you, you should show us what you tried. My example happens to be returning JSON, but the idea is identical in HTML.